# How does Chrome know how to format Microsoft Excel exported HTML without specifying the stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, excel, google-chrome

Never mind. Excel does generate .xl99999 styles in a `<header>`. When this rich text editor value is set with HTML content, it adds the styles but when you try to get the value later, it only returns the `<body>` tag and strips the styles. I saw the contents after getting the value and submitting to the server. I guess you could say there is a bug in the rich text editor, but I will attempt to work around it.

---

How does Chrome know how to format these CSS classes exported from Microsoft Excel into HTML when I never specified the stylesheet to use? It is just a pure HTML string that was sent via an API so there is no stylesheet definitions. The class .xl6613001 is never defined, nor any others. So how does Chrome know to use a given background color?

[Minus http://i.minus.com/iX77mOMM3dNNS.png](http://i.minus.com/iX77mOMM3dNNS.png)

Here is the [full output from Excel](http://pastie.org/8611108). Notice the lack of color styles.

The rich text editor is com.gc.gwt.wysiwyg.client.Editor, https://code.google.com/p/gwt-html-editor/wiki/GettingStarted.

I searched the Resources tab for '.xl' and nothing was found.

It does not format colors if I look at the raw HTML as a file.

Comment: My Chrome doesn't know how to do it, I think you might have a browser plugin installed which does the trick for you. It would be useful if you added a screenshot of the markup of the `head` section of the page in the developer tools. I think a plugin might have added a stylesheet there.

Comment: I copied your full output from Excel into a new html document. No styles for me...